# Increase a http get request connection Timeout in Angular2 http module

Tags: https, timeout

I use Angular2 on the client side and Node in the backend. I am trying to keep the https connection open until it timesout in 4 hours.

In the backend I tried, calling this but it still timesout at default 2 minutes

`request.timeout(1000 * 60 * 60 * 4, function(){})`

Since I use Angular2 http module. I tried using timeout method in http request as follows, this timesout at default of 2 minutes:

`return this.http.get(this.URL, {search : params, withCredentials: true})
      .map(res => res.json())
      .timeout(1000 * 60 * 60 * 4)
      .catch(this.handleError);`

Any other suggestions to increase https request connection from default 2 minutes to 4 hours

Answer (score 0):

Following are some of the suggestions:

- It is not a good design to wait for 4 hours for the response.Try changing the back-end for quicker responses
- Adding **requestTimeout** to the web.config file of the project fixed the issue for me

  ```
  <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:10:00" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
  ```